# Desktop loads around 5-6 minutes after I log in - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, black-screen-of-death

I am using Windows 10 Version 1703 Build 15063.540. After I log-in, I get a Black Screen with cursor. Normal desktop loads after around 5-6 minutes in this "blacked-out" mode. I am able to open task manager.

Things I've tried so far

1. Ctrl+alt+del to open Task Manager and tried running "explorer.exe". Explorer is already running and the black screen remains.
2. Boot into Safe Mode to disable Intel Display driver.
3. Boot into Safe Mode to uninstall Intel Display driver.
4. Update the display drivers.
5. Disabled Fast-boot
6. Run Component tests (Using built in HP diagnostic tools). My tests were successful.
7. Run start-up repair in System recovery.
8. Uninstalled VMware and its network cards.
9. Checked "Startup" in Task manager. Found nothing which could delay startup. I've Internet download manager, HP Accelerometer, HP Radio Manager, NVidia Capture Proxy and an AutoHot key script(disabling this script had no effect).

I enabled boot log in msconfig>Boot
My windows fails to load

```
> BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\WdFilter.sys
> BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
> BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\CAD.sys
```

The thing which amazes me the most is that Desktop loads after exactly 6min 26sec (+- 2  sec). And I am observing this value over 5 tries.

Comment: What have you tried specifically?  Telling us you tried all solution for your problem doesn't tell us anything helpful.  What will happen is you will just get answers with solutions you already ruled out.  So please edit your question and provide all relevant information so we can help you

Comment: If you create a new user do you get the same black-screen when logging in as that one?

Comment: Did you try to boot into safe mode? When did this issue start occuring? Did anything change on your PC that could have caused that e.g. a new software/driver etc you installed?

Comment: Looked into the eventlog to see if any services fail to start or other stuff? Windows is apparently having difficulty at boot, and the eventlog is very useful troubleshooting these.

Comment: Check Task Manager, Startup tab, to see what might be delaying boot. It could be AV scan, Windows updates etc.

Comment: Please describe the "black screen of death". A "...screen of death" usually means the computer is forcibly restarted, but in your situation that does not appear to be the case. Instead, based on your description, it appears that one or more system processes are failing to start properly, and therefore the Desktop Window Manager and/or Explorer.exe are failing to load until some time-out occurs.

Comment: I've updated the question with things I've tried so far

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and here is what I did to fix it: Update group policy.

Open command prompt and run the command GPUPDATE /FORCE 
If it fails to update then make sure that the NETLOGON service is running and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment - not enough rep

Normally this happens either if you're connecting to a domain AD or if you have a lot of things on your desktop that it's trying to load

Say you have around 6GB of stuff on your desktop the computer has to load that EVERY time you login

Comment: Nothing on my desktop. Not even the system icons. I've disabled them all

Comment: Does the problem persist on your safe mode boots? if it does that indicates it's a problem with one of the drivers that it tries to load on startup

Comment: Safe mode works absolutely fine. I tried disabling and uninstalling the display adapter but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Only other thing that comes to mind is the network driver failing

Comment: All those errors point to a hardware or software failure, try rolling back / uninstalling anything you have installed over the past couple of days one at a time

Uninstall it, restart does it solve the problem? No then re-install and try something else

Comment: You try using Windows Performance Recorder to determine where exactly Windows hangs on startup: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448205.aspx

Comment: dxgkrnl.sys is a DirectX driver updated and installed ONLY using windows update. Is it possible that the Win update broke this driver.

Comment: However, according to my boot log the driver loads successfully first and then later fails to load 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

I've a possible solution to this (This solution worked for me).
I used a script to set custom scaling. I think the display driver update caused that error. Resetting the script fixed this problem.

This seemed to fix my problem however after a recent Windows update I ran into the same problem AGAIN..!! This time resetting the script didn't work :(